# Adding In-App Purchase Entitlement to iOS App Messes Up Code Signing

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, code-signing, provisioning-profile

Pulling my hair out over this. I have an iOS app. If in-app purchase is turned off under Capabilities, everything works fine. I can archive the app and submit it to the app store with no problems. Code singing in build settings is this:

[image]

If I turn on in-app purchases in the capabilities, I get an error in Xcode when I try to archive the app:

```
No matching provisioning profiles found: None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified capabilities: Features: inAppPurchase..
```

[image]

If I set my provisioning profile to my distribution profile and my identity to my distribution identity, the app successfully archives in Xcode, but gives an error when submitting to the store.

[image]

```
Xcode attempted to locate or generate matching signing assets and failed to do so because of the following issues.

No matching provisioning profiles found for "Applications/AppName.app..."
```

[image]

I've tried deleting my ID under preferences>account and adding it again. I created a new distribution profile and used that. Deleted my signing identities in keychain and reinstalled them. Nothing seems to work. Why would it work when in-app purchase is turned off then not when it is turned on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh!!! I had somehow created a development profile that I thought was a distribution profile. I created a new distribution profile and now everything works.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your AppID does not have "In-App Purchases" assigned to it. Login to Apple Member Center and goto App IDs. Verify your application has "In-App Purchase" Application Service checked. If not, check it, and re-generate a Provisioning Profile for your app.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This wasn't the problem but it made me look at my provisioning profiles and I realized my mistake.